# Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a Nexus 7 with Marshmallow, it seems I'm no longer able to access the device storage.

Previously, from the Android Studio Device Monitor's File Explorer I could access mnt/shell/emulated/0 to access the device's "external" storage.

Now, with Marshmallow, it seems mnt/shell is gone. Is there any way to access this same storage location?

Comment: As far as I know, it has moved to somewhere in /data folder.

Comment: my /data folder is empty....

Comment: Check in /storage for a folder like /storage/sdcard0

Answer (score 0):

You need to root your device before, or just running the app on an emulator. If you do this the data file will not be empty and you will be able to access to your device data.